# Uniquely identify iOS devices using Appium

Tags: appium

I'm using Appium with several iPhones.

I was wondering if it is possible for Appium to get some value such as (UUID, IMEI, or device serial number), which can be used to uniquely identify the device.

Comment: `identifierForVendor` is the value you should use - I am not sure how/if this is available in Appium but perhaps this will give you a clue of what to search for.

Comment: This is usable in iOS only (in the device) as far as I can see. Appium works with Java, on my Mac and I was wondering if there was a way for Appium to get a unique ID.

Comment: Sorry, you should probably remove the iOS tag then...

Comment: My apologies. Removed.

Comment: Would it be reasonable if you could use a shell command to get a list of all possible iOS devices?

Comment: So the shell command would get all the iOS device ID's connected to the machine via USB? If so, that would be something to go along. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Any news with this issue?

Comment: @Elad Here's an update. I can use an iOS app I developed to get the UDID or serial number. I was thinking of saving that number in the device in some format which appium can read. But I have no clue on what format or place is best to save this data. That's all I've gotten so far.

Comment: @donga Thanks. I'll keep searching..

Answer (score 2):

In terminal you can do the command `instruments -s devices` and the output will look something like this

```
instruments -s devices
Resizable iPad (8.1 Simulator) [C4CA3A6A-4638-4AA3-ADE0-EF52DC4A2792]
Resizable iPhone (8.1 Simulator) [26E026B6-7183-4D34-A959-8D33F82AF242]
iPad 2 (8.1 Simulator) [FC58D378-D382-49BB-A7B6-F249D21BCD6C]
iPad Air (8.1 Simulator) [963F1E76-5513-4CDD-8C81-B7774747D5DF]
iPad Retina (8.1 Simulator) [F3169876-C767-4F27-84C4-00A8A5DE3AE0]
iPhone 4s (8.1 Simulator) [1FAB83AD-4B58-46BF-B88A-FBCDC0E7B199]
iPhone 5 (8.1 Simulator) [2106BB0C-52B2-4413-B65E-8B6D20D711C9]
iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator) [EC34641A-F102-4ECE-A92C-3EE7B52027C1]
iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator) [4B1C21E5-F795-4EEE-807B-3DD310D089B6]
iPhone 6 Plus (8.1 Simulator) [6FEC1EAC-50DE-4093-8585-CD55C7E3BC48]
```

When you have physical devices connected they will appear at the top of this list. You'll notice between the `[]` is the UUID of each device. So you can create a small script to use this command to generate a list and then parse out the real devices from the top of the list, parse out the UUID from all real devices (or sims if you prefer in a different scenario).

Answer (score 1):

Use UDID number can be used to uniquely identify the device.

Easy Way .. Copy/Paste from iTunes

```
Launch iTunes and connect your iPhone.
In the right pane, locate the information about your iPhone, including its name, capacity, software version, serial number, and phone number.
Reveal the Identifier by clicking on Serial Number:. Copy the Identifier to your clipboard by choosing Edit → Copy.
```

Get the UDID using iTunes on a PC/Mac

Answer (score 1):

Try this command from terminal it will display the connected devices udid

```
idevice_id -l
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is of solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].